# Re-format unreadable JSON to readable JSON on android

Tags: java, android, json, escaping

How can I re-format such a response. I need to escape **\t** and **\n**. I have tried to reformat by replacing "" but it won't work. This is a valid JSON response from the API. Also i have used `JSONTokener` but none worked.

> "\n \t{\n\t\t\t \"id\": \"567DITR\",\n\t\t\t\t\"URL\":
>   \"http://test.com/visa/wallet/debit-auth/code?autcode=‌​yueyuw77676&ref_id=0‌​909343SSDSDS&lang=en‌​g\", \n\t\t\t\t\"CODE\": \"OI08989pk3MKPITXN\",\n\t\t\t\t\"created_at\":
>   \"Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:07:08 UTC\"\n\t\t\t}\n "

i need something like this:

> {   "id":"23",   "dept":"ICT" }

Comment: Is this the response from the web service? Does it include `\t`, `\n` and escape slashes?

Comment: yes it does, i tried to post it on jsonprettyprint.com and it works. it includes \n and \t @K Neeraj Lal

Comment: When I try it on jsonprettyprint.com, it says null. Where did the `+` characters come from?

Comment: "\n           \t{\n\t\t\t    \"id\": \"567DITR\",\n\t\t\t\t\"URL\": \"http:\/\/test.com\/visa\/wallet\/debit-auth\/code?autcode=yueyuw77676&ref_id=0909343SSDSDS&lang=eng\",  \n\t\t\t\t\"CODE\": \"OI08989pk3MKPITXN\",\n\t\t\t\t\"created_at\": \"Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:07:08 UTC\"\n\t\t\t}\n       "        @K Neeraj Lal

Comment: test this please @K Neeraj Lal

Comment: Yeah, this seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\\\\n", jsonStr);
        jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\\\\t", jsonStr);
         jsonStr = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Try this

Comment: This works @Sahil Manchanda. With slight modification i was able to get the right format. thanks